# If we remove the sample code and submit a new version for the security review, will there be an 'again payment required' for the submission

Tags: appexchange, security-review

We recently submitted our package for the AppExchange security review, but unfortunately, it did not pass. The security review team indicated that, according to the Security Review Guidelines, 'the sample code needs to be removed from the source code before deploying it to Production'. We want to clarify that the inclusion of sample code was not intentional, and interestingly, the Checkmarx security scanning process did not identify it as a vulnerability.

To address this issue, I have created a case to remove the component feature from the package. My question is, **if we remove the sample code and submit a new version for the security review, will there be an 'again payment required' for the submission**?

Comment: I expect you'll have to pay again unless you can persuade someone at Salesforce (e.g. your account manager) to provide a fee waiver voucher...